# Looking to Optimize this Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, query-optimization

I have an extremely long running query running against our data warehouse, and need to see how we can optimize it.  The [AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log] table has 105 million rows.  Here is the query.

```
select a.Nationid,count(a.Nationid)as nationcount from 
    (select replace(replace(convert(nvarchar(MAX),[parameters]), '<root><nationid>', ''),'</nationid></root>','') as Nationid
    from [AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log]
    where username not like '%erieri.com' and "Parameters" is not null) as a
group by a.Nationid
```

Here are the indexes on the table.

- IX_Log   nonclustered located on PRIMARY Timestamp
- IX_Log_1 nonclustered located on PRIMARY Type
- IX_Log_3 nonclustered located on PRIMARY AppCode
- IX_Log_4 nonclustered located on PRIMARY ServiceNamespace
- IX_Log_5 nonclustered located on PRIMARY ServiceName
- IX_Log_6 nonclustered located on PRIMARY MethodName
- IX_Log_7 nonclustered located on PRIMARY Duration
- IX_Log_MethodName    nonclustered located on PRIMARY SubscriptionCode, MethodName
- IX_Log_UserName  nonclustered located on PRIMARY UserName, SubscriptionCode, MethodName, Timestamp
- IX_Log_UserNameDate  nonclustered located on PRIMARY UserName, Timestamp, SubscriptionCode
- ix_TypeAppCodeMethodName nonclustered located on PRIMARY Type, AppCode, MethodName, Timestamp
- PK_Log   clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY   DWid

Here is the execution plan:

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.3.1" Build="12.0.5207.0"><BatchSequence><Batch><Statements><StmtSimple StatementText="select a.Nationid,count(a.Nationid)as nationcount from &#xD;&#xA;    (select replace(replace(convert(nvarchar(MAX),[parameters]), '&lt;root&gt;&lt;nationid&gt;', ''),'&lt;/nationid&gt;&lt;/root&gt;','') as Nationid&#xD;&#xA;    from [AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log]&#xD;&#xA;    where username not like '%erieri.com' and &quot;Parameters&quot; is not null) as a&#xD;&#xA;group by a.Nationid" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="1" StatementType="SELECT" RetrievedFromCache="true" StatementSubTreeCost="18373.7" StatementEstRows="8240.4" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" QueryHash="0x288FAF0B2CDAA4D5" QueryPlanHash="0xBC649190D004A5F1" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70"><StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" /><QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="56" CompileTime="27" CompileCPU="12" CompileMemory="672"><ThreadStat Branches="2" /><MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="1536" SerialDesiredMemory="83680" /><OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="256000" EstimatedPagesCached="64000" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" MaxCompileMemory="2424384" /><TraceFlags IsCompileTime="1"><TraceFlag Value="845" Scope="Global" /><TraceFlag Value="1117" Scope="Global" /><TraceFlag Value="1118" Scope="Global" /><TraceFlag Value="3226" Scope="Global" /><TraceFlag Value="4199" Scope="Global" /></TraceFlags><RelOp NodeId="1" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimateRows="16480.8" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.00164808" AvgRowSize="4039" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18373.7" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" /></OutputList><ComputeScalar><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" /><ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[globalagg1009],0)"><Convert DataType="int" Style="0" Implicit="1"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="globalagg1009" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><RelOp NodeId="2" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" LogicalOp="Gather Streams" EstimateRows="16480.8" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="2.34046" AvgRowSize="4043" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18373.7" Parallel="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ColumnReference Column="globalagg1009" /></OutputList><Parallelism><RelOp NodeId="3" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" LogicalOp="Aggregate" EstimateRows="16480.8" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.00906444" AvgRowSize="4043" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18371.3" Parallel="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ColumnReference Column="globalagg1009" /></OutputList><StreamAggregate><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="globalagg1009" /><ScalarOperator ScalarString="SUM([partialagg1008])"><Aggregate Distinct="0" AggType="SUM"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="partialagg1008" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Aggregate></ScalarOperator></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><GroupBy><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /></GroupBy><RelOp NodeId="4" PhysicalOp="Sort" LogicalOp="Sort" EstimateRows="16480.8" EstimateIO="0.00563063" EstimateCPU="0.529902" AvgRowSize="4043" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18371.3" Parallel="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ColumnReference Column="partialagg1008" /></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" /><Sort Distinct="0"><OrderBy><OrderByColumn Ascending="1"><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /></OrderByColumn></OrderBy><RelOp NodeId="5" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" LogicalOp="Repartition Streams" EstimateRows="16480.8" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="3.98045" AvgRowSize="4043" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18370.8" Parallel="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ColumnReference Column="partialagg1008" /></OutputList><Parallelism PartitioningType="Hash"><PartitionColumns><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /></PartitionColumns><RelOp NodeId="6" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" LogicalOp="Partial Aggregate" EstimateRows="16480.8" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="276.148" AvgRowSize="4043" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18366.8" Parallel="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ColumnReference Column="partialagg1008" /></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="0" Output="0" /><Hash><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="partialagg1008" /><ScalarOperator ScalarString="COUNT(replace(replace([Expr1006],N'&lt;root&gt;&lt;nationid&gt;',CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),'',0)),N'&lt;/nationid&gt;&lt;/root&gt;',CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),'',0)))"><Aggregate Distinct="0" AggType="COUNT_BIG"><ScalarOperator><Intrinsic FunctionName="replace"><ScalarOperator><Intrinsic FunctionName="replace"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="N'&lt;root&gt;&lt;nationid&gt;'" /></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1005"><ScalarOperator><Convert DataType="nvarchar(max)" Length="2147483647" Style="0" Implicit="1"><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="''" /></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></ColumnReference></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="N'&lt;/nationid&gt;&lt;/root&gt;'" /></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1004"><ScalarOperator><Convert DataType="nvarchar(max)" Length="2147483647" Style="0" Implicit="1"><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="''" /></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></ColumnReference></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator></Aggregate></ScalarOperator></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><HashKeysBuild><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /></HashKeysBuild><BuildResidual><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Expr1002] = [Expr1002]"><Compare CompareOp="IS"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></BuildResidual><RelOp NodeId="7" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimateRows="6.79042e+007" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="3.39521" AvgRowSize="8061" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18090.7" Parallel="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" /></OutputList><ComputeScalar><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ScalarOperator ScalarString="replace(replace([Expr1007],N'&lt;root&gt;&lt;nationid&gt;',CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),'',0)),N'&lt;/nationid&gt;&lt;/root&gt;',CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),'',0))"><Intrinsic FunctionName="replace"><ScalarOperator><Intrinsic FunctionName="replace"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="N'&lt;root&gt;&lt;nationid&gt;'" /></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1005"><ScalarOperator><Convert DataType="nvarchar(max)" Length="2147483647" Style="0" Implicit="1"><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="''" /></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></ColumnReference></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="N'&lt;/nationid&gt;&lt;/root&gt;'" /></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1004"><ScalarOperator><Convert DataType="nvarchar(max)" Length="2147483647" Style="0" Implicit="1"><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="''" /></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></ColumnReference></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><RelOp NodeId="8" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimateRows="6.79042e+007" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="3.39521" AvgRowSize="8061" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18087.3" Parallel="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" /><ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" /></OutputList><ComputeScalar><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" /><ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT(nvarchar(max),[AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log].[Parameters],0)"><Convert DataType="nvarchar(max)" Length="2147483647" Style="0" Implicit="0"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[AssessorLogDW]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Log]" Column="Parameters" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" /><ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT(nvarchar(max),[AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log].[Parameters],0)"><Convert DataType="nvarchar(max)" Length="2147483647" Style="0" Implicit="0"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[AssessorLogDW]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Log]" Column="Parameters" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><RelOp NodeId="9" PhysicalOp="Filter" LogicalOp="Filter" EstimateRows="6.79042e+007" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="72.688" AvgRowSize="4035" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18083.9" Parallel="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[AssessorLogDW]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Log]" Column="Parameters" /></OutputList><Filter StartupExpression="0"><RelOp NodeId="10" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" LogicalOp="Index Scan" EstimateRows="6.79042e+007" EstimateIO="17953.2" EstimateCPU="57.9398" AvgRowSize="4060" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="18011.2" TableCardinality="1.05345e+008" Parallel="1" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[AssessorLogDW]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Log]" Column="Parameters" /></OutputList><Warnings><ColumnsWithNoStatistics><ColumnReference Database="[AssessorLogDW]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Log]" Column="Parameters" /></ColumnsWithNoStatistics></Warnings><IndexScan Ordered="0" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[AssessorLogDW]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Log]" Column="Parameters" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[AssessorLogDW]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Log]" Index="[ix_TypeAppCodeMethodName]" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" /><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="NOT [AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log].[UserName] like '%erieri.com'"><Logical Operation="NOT"><ScalarOperator><Intrinsic FunctionName="like"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[AssessorLogDW]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Log]" Column="UserName" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="'%erieri.com'" /></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator></Logical></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log].[Parameters] IS NOT NULL"><Compare CompareOp="IS NOT"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[AssessorLogDW]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Log]" Column="Parameters" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="NULL" /></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Predicate></Filter></RelOp></ComputeScalar></RelOp></ComputeScalar></RelOp></Hash></RelOp></Parallelism></RelOp></Sort></RelOp></StreamAggregate></RelOp></Parallelism></RelOp></ComputeScalar></RelOp></QueryPlan></StmtSimple></Statements></Batch></BatchSequence></ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Try a filtered index with exactly the same filter expression that your query has

Comment: Without looking at your execution plan, I can tell you that your index on `username` cannot be used because your `like` predicate is looking for a string that starts with a wildcard.  As far as I know, SQL Server does not allow you to use build a computed index.

Comment: Two questions: 1) How many [average] rows are you selecting out of the 105M? 2) The pattern against username is it variable or always the same one?

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the schema? Adding an "username domain" column that persists just the part after the % sign would allow you to index and then filter out those users more efficiently than scanning the entire table to match against a leading wildcard. Is the schema fixed?

Comment: How long is `parameters`?  SQL Server could be pushing the string calculation to the node that reads the data.  That means it would be calculated on all rows, and if `parameters` is quite large, then running that code on all rows could be a significant slow-down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to avoid `subquery` :

```
select Nationid, count(*) as nationcount 
from [AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log] l1 cross apply
     ( values (replace(replace(convert(nvarchar(max), [parameters]), '<root><nationid>', ''),'</nationid></root>','') 
              )
     ) l2(Nationid)
where username not like '%erieri.com' and 
      [parameters] is not null
group by Nationid;
```

Comment: @scsimon. . . I just provided alternate approach & i can't measure the performance without seeing `Execution plan`.

Comment: Totally agree and I think yours may be better I was just hoping to see both plans

Comment: A cross apply as suggested here will not likely change the performance.  its just syntactic sugar

Answer (score 1):

@rtoyo is correct.  The problem is the leading wildcard.  What are the actual possibilities for that column?  Maybe you can get the same result without the leading wildcard.  if erieri.com is a domain, can you get the list of subdomains?  If so, you can use that to construct a join on that part of the name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what's the selectivity on this query, so I'll assume it's a good one that will allow an index to be used. There are two things I would do:

- The plan you posted warns there are no statistics for the `parameters` column of the `Log` table. When optimizing you need to make sure the stats are up to date. So first of all run:

  ```
  update statistics [AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log];
  ```
- Then, to radically improve the speed of your query you'll need to minimize the Index Range Scan, in order to walk the smallest possible number of index leaf nodes. If speed is really important for you I would:

  - Create a virtual column:

    ```
    alter table log add reverse_username as reverse(username);
    ```
  - Create two new indexes that use the virtual column (let the optimizer pick the best one):

    ```
    create index ix1_log on log (parameters, reverse_username);
    create index ix2_log on log (reverse_username, parameters);
    ```
  - Change the query a little bit to make full use of the new index:

    ```
    select a.Nationid,count(a.Nationid)as nationcount from 
        (select replace(replace(convert(nvarchar(MAX),[parameters]),
          '<root><nationid>', ''),'</nationid></root>','') as Nationid
        from [AssessorLogDW].[dbo].[Log]
        where reverse_username not like reverse('%erieri.com')
          and "Parameters" is not null) as a
    group by a.Nationid
    ```

The trick is to search using the reverse username in order to place the wildcard at the end. That opens the possibility to make the best use of the index with a small "range". The index walk will be short and fast.

Comment: We will probably use this method.  The only snag is `parameters` is XML, so I don't believe we can index that.

Comment: Your condition against `parameters` checks if it's null or not null. You can add another virtual column that returns `0` or `1` for it and query against this one. This column can be easily indexed to make it fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can create indexed view in SQL Server.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199058/SQL-Server-Indexed-Views-Speed-Up-Your-Select-Quer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for offering some help. In general, it's best to answer the poster's question, and, if it's useful, offer a link that provides additional information if they want to dig further. Maybe edit your answer to include how an indexed view would work to address the OP's problem. There are good guidelines on how to answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer